# How to convert IP address to integer using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 2 problem statements

## 1:

I need to read read an IP address from a text file and increment the value by 1 and store it in a variable. This all I have to do using a batch script.

This is how my text file looks like -

```
MyIpAddressList.txt
192.168.1.105
```

I am able to read it as string and store & print it

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (IPADDRESSLIST.txt) do set /p IPAddress=%%x+1
ECHO %IPAddress%
```

But when I am trying to read it as number as mentioned `set /a IPAddress=%%x+1"` it doesn't work.

## 2:

I have to run a loop for 100 times and pass this IP address as an
input to another batch script and increment this ip address by 1.

Example:

Main_Batch_File.bat

```
READ MyIpAddressList.txt and store IP address in IPAddress
IPAddress = 192.168.1.105
LOOP 100 times
CALL Another_Batch_Script(IPAddress)
IPAddress++
LOOP END
```

I am not sure if it is possible using a batch file and apologise if this does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in (%ipaddress%) do (
  set/a suffix=1%%d-1000
  for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do (
    set/a suffix+=1
    call "yourscript.bat" %%a.%%b.%%c.!suffix! 
  )
```

first we split *ipaddress* in four tokens. then handle the fourth.
the `set/a suffix=1%%d-1000` avoids numbers below 100 (i.e 080) being treated as octal

EDIT: as TripeHound suggested, if you need to start from current address, move the increment behind the call statement.

Comment: +1 This will probably do what the OP wants (possibly moving the increment after the call), but will produce invalid IP addresses if the start is `x.x.x.155` or above (would need extra logic to either wrap at 255 or increment the next component).

Comment: @TripeHound, yes. but if the OP knows how to read from a file, sure knows how to handle whatever the requirements are. Also, IMHO, changing net class possibly it is not intended.

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, I just felt it was worth pointing out that with, say, `192.168.1.192` then it would cycle through `192.168.1.256` and beyond (while leaving it as an exercise for the OP if it matters to them).

Comment: it wasn't critisism too, again IMO the question is not as clear as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

elzoologico's solution expanded to avoid the "overflow" problem, TripeHound mentioned:

```
@echo off
set ipaddress=192.168.001.015
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%ipaddress%") do (
  set /a suffix=1%%d-1000
  set /a final=suffix+100
  if !final! gtr 255 set final=255
  for /l %%i in (!suffix!,1,!final!) do (
    ECHO call "yourscript.bat" %%a.%%b.%%c.%%i 
  )
)
```